# Java regex: multiple matches in positive lookahead and lookbehind

Tags: java, regex

I have some strings like this

- `my  {test} value`
- `my  {   test     } value`
- `my  { test  } value`

I need to create a regex that will get everything inside `{}` without spaces.

With the next pattern `(?<=\{)\s*[a-zA-Z]+\s*(?=})` I get the content of curly brackets but with spaces

[image]

If I put `\s*` to positive lookahead like this `(?<=\{\s*)[a-zA-Z]+(?=\s*})` I see next error

> Unable to execute regular expression. java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length near index 8 (?<={\s*)[a-zA-Z]+(?=\s*}) ^

Is it possible to achieve this without `trim()` of every regex match?

Comment: You do not need lookbehind, use `\{\s*([a-zA-Z]+)(?=\s*})` and grab Group 1.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, why the lookahead in the end?

Comment: @jrook A force of habt, lookaheads in the anchored positions are more efficient and allow  overlapping matches. Not the case here though, but still good to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need look ahead or look behind. Simple regex like this is enough,

```
\{\s*(.*?)\s*\}
```

Demo,
https://regex101.com/r/REDmDT/2 (included some more sample strings)

Like you said, "I need to create a regex that will get everything inside {} without spaces"

This regex gives you everything within curley braces while excluding right /left spaces and preserving any spaces inside as it is.

Here is a java code demonstrating same.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("my  {test} value", "my  {   test     } value", "my  { test  } value",
            "my  { test hello I am  } value", "my  { testing 10 times  } value");
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{\\s*(.*?)\\s*\\}");

    list.forEach(x -> {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(x);
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(x + " --> " + m.group(1));
        }
    });
}
```

This outputs,

```
my  {test} value --> test
my  {   test     } value --> test
my  { test  } value --> test
my  { test hello I am  } value --> test hello I am
my  { testing 10 times  } value --> testing 10 times
```